# Do I need to Crypto Base64 a file in order to upload it to an API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is it recommended to first use the CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 a file content before uploading it to an API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not needed and not recommended. In fact it's not on the encoding specification and will possibly be incompatible with existing multiform/form-data parsers.